SQL Count Time Spent on Every Status
I have the following table in SQL:



ID
CreatedDate
OldValue
NewValue




1
18/11/2024 13:05:10
Open
Escalated


1
18/11/2024 14:05:10
Escalated
With Customer


1
18/11/2024 16:05:10
With Customer
Closed


2
20/11/2024 09:00:00
Open
In Progress


2
18/11/2024 12:00:00
In Progress
Escalated


2
18/11/2024 18:00:00
Escalated
Closed



I would like to create a column for every distinct status value I have and count how much time (In hour) the case was spent on every status.
Here is the desired output for the status "Escalated" for example:



ID
CreatedDate
OldValue
NewValue
TimeSpentEscalatedStatus




1
18/11/2024 13:05:10
Open
Escalated
1


1
18/11/2024 14:05:10
Escalated
With Customer
1


1
18/11/2024 16:05:10
With Customer
Closed
1


2
20/11/2024 09:00:00
Open
In Progress
4


2
18/11/2024 12:00:00
In Progress
Escalated
4


2
18/11/2024 18:00:00
Escalated
Closed
4



Thank you very much in advance for the help.

I don't understand the example. ID 1 was in Escalated from 13:05 to 14:05 = 1 hour. Okay. ID 2, though, was in Escalated from 12:00 to 18:00 = 6 hours, but you are showing 4. Why? And how would you deal with fractions of hours (like from 13:05 to 13:20 for instance)?

And you want to write a separate query for each status? Or somehow give the query a parameter with the required status? Or have several columns, one for each status? (If the latter, you must know all statuses at the time you write the query.)

I am not familiar with Cloudera, but if it supports subqueries as SELECT expressions, you can use a subquery to find the row with the same id, later CreatedDate and different NewState (this maybe redundant):
select
   ID
   ,CreatedDate
   ,OldValue
   ,NewValue 
   , (select datediff(MINUTE, tr.CreatedDate, min(nr.CreatedDate))/60.
      from MyTbl NR
      where NR.Id=TR.Id
      and NR.CreatedDate>TR.CreatedDate
      and NR.OldValue=TR.NewValue) as HoursInNewState
from MyTbl TR

I used datediff of SQLServer, but you might need to substitute with the function calculating time-differences (TIMESTAMP_DIFF??)
